# Getting errors on declaring date in symfony

Tags: symfony, datetime

How to declare date and time in symfony? When I declare them, it is giving me errors like expecting date while declaring string and all. Please provide the correct format for date.

This is what I did:

```
$time = "09:11";
$date = "22-07-2019"

$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setDate(new \DateTime($date));
$entity->setTime($time);
```

Comment: can you update your question with some code on how you tried to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you split date and time to two fields, use one field for both.
Use this to convert string to datetime:

```
$format = 'd-m-Y H:i'; (for example)
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '22-07-2019 09:11');
```